# Simulating the spread of a virus from an infected individual to a susceptible individual in a small world network using netlogo?

Tags: simulation, netlogo, virus

I am simulating the spread of a virus across a small world network in netlogo. Using the existing model netlogo offers of a small world network where nodes can connect with other nodes using the 'Rewire One' button on the interface I am trying to get it so that if an initially infected individual gets rewired with a susceptible individual the virus will then transfer to that individual and the turtles color will update to red.
Here is the code im using to rewire one turtle with another:

```
    to rewire-one

if count turtles != num-nodes [
setup
]


 set rewire-one? true
 set rewire-all? false

 let potential-edges links with [ not rewired? ]
 ifelse any? potential-edges [
 ask one-of potential-edges [

  let node1 end1
  ;; if "a" is not connected to everybody
  if [ count link-neighbors ] of end1 < (count turtles - 1)
  [
    ;; find a node distinct from node1 and not already a neighbor of node1
    let node2 one-of turtles with [ (self != node1) and (not link-neighbor?       node1) ]
    ;; wire the new edge
    ask node1 [ create-link-with node2 [ set color cyan  set rewired? true ] ]


    ask links
[ reed-frost-children]

ask links
[ increment-children ]

    set number-rewired number-rewired + 1  ;; counter for number of rewirings


    ;; remove the old edge
    die
  ]
  ]
```

;;I am then using the reed-frost function as the force of infection which can be seen below

```
to reed-frost-children

ask children with [ child-sus = 1] 
[
set num-infected-neighbours length filter [[ child-infected = 1] of ?]
[other-end] of my-links with [not rewired?] ;; i.e not closed? i.e open 

  set force-of-infection 1 - (1 - prob-infection-child) ^ num-infected-   neighbours

if(random-float 1 <= force-of-infection)
[
  set child-sus 0
  set child-inncubated 1
  set child-infected 0
  set child-almost-infected 0
  set child-recovered 0


  set inncubation-period 100
  show-turtle
  set color orange
  set size 1

  ask link-neighbors with [ child-infected = 1]
  [
    ask my-links 
    [
      set color orange show-link

      ask other-end
      [
        set color orange
      ]
    ]
  ]

  ask my-links [set closed? false] ;; closed i.e. not open
]
]
```

However the virus is not transmitting when an infected rewires with a susceptible. Any ideas?